# WPEWebKit does not starts on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, webkit

In general I done all steps from [WPEWebkit readme](https://github.com/WebPlatformForEmbedded/WPEWebKit/blob/wpe-20170728/README.md) to launch WPE on Ubuntu 16.04.

Prerequisites and dependencies (`Tools/Scripts/update-webkitwpe-libs`) installed without errors.
Release build compiled (`Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --wpe`) without errors.

In first terminal I executed: `weston --socket=wpe`. Weston Window shown.
In second terminal: `WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wpe Tools/Scripts/run-minibrowser --wpe`. Terminal displays only: "Starting MiniBrowser." and hangs. Nothing appeared on Weston Window.

In `htop` command I see `MiniBrowser`, `WPENetworkProcess` and `WPEWebProcess` but each of them has in VIRT column very big values: about 97GB.

[image]

I also tried to use this [script](https://people.igalia.com/clopez/run-wpe-x11) from [trac.webkit.org](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WPE), with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, WPEWebKit works correctly on XOrg (with `weston --socket=wpe`) and Wayland.